# Background-size animation doesn't work on safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, zooming, css-animations

I have an keyframe that slowly zooms in and out of my main page background image that is rendered through css background image.  It works great on chrome and firefox but not safari. Here is what I have.

```
@keyframes shrink {
  0% {background-size: 100% 100%;}
  100% {background-size: 115% 115%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
  0% {background-size: 100% 100%;}
  100% {background-size: 115% 115%;}
}

@-ms-keyframes shrink {
  0% {background-size: 100% 100%;}
  100% {background-size: 115% 115%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes shrink {
  0% {background-size: 100% 100%;}
  100% {background-size: 115% 115%;}
}

@-0-keyframes shrink {
  0% {background-size: 100% 100%;}
  100% {background-size: 115% 115%;}
}


.header_container {
  animation: shrink 20s infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: shrink 20s infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: shrink 20s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: shrink 20s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: shrink 20s infinite alternate linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("https://github.com/luciogutz/");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

What am I missing. I have version 10 safari.

Comment: Did you test this on a MAC or emulator ( like browserstack )?

Comment: Can you please provide a working code snippet please?

Comment: I tried it on my MAC

Comment: Here is a link to the code on codepen  https://codepen.io/luciogutz/pen/prGxXP

Answer (score 5):

Setting the final state in "style" did the trick when I had the same issue. In your example this works:

```
<section class="header_container" style="background-size: 115% 115%;"></section>
```